# Removing duplicates from search results

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a list of products that look like this:

```
{"name": "", "image_url":"", tags:0}
```

The problem is, there are a fair amount of duplicate products. There is no real way to control adding duplicates to elasticsearch because of the sheer size of the data, so I'm looking for a way to filter out duplicates at query time.

Duplicate products are defined as "products with the same name and image_url field". Also, if a product has more than zero "tags", then we never want to remove it from search results!

Any ideas how I can get this done?

Comment: Considered basing the document's ID on e.g. the MD5 of the contents?

Comment: I can't because documents change a lot and the IDs are permanent.

Comment: @AndrewVos, I don't think it is possible with just elasticsearch query. You have to handle this at application level it self.

Comment: Have you had any experience with aggregations like `top_hits`, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. There are several possible ways.

1 - You can handle the issue at the time of indexing. In my code I created a Java derby DB storing the index content. DB's table had a primary key on index content. When new index arrives, I try to insert it into the DB. If the content is unique, it is inserted into the DB and I insert the index into the ES. If the primary key is violated (the content already existed), I will not ingest it into ES.

2 - Ingest everything into the ES. Runs a script on daily/hourly basis that download the content and queries the ES. If it finds a duplicity, removes it.